# Trying to Count 2 days from an original date to flag a late response

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates, google-sheets-data-validation

I need a formula that will provide this conditional formatting in Google Sheets. Please help.

Column H = Date the request was sent
Column I = Date the response was received

I need to ensure I have a response within 2 days of sending the request. So I want column I to update to Yellow 1 day after the request was sent (Column H) & Red 2 days or more after the request was sent (Column H) so I know I need to escalate for a response. What formula could I use in Conditional Format rules?

Comment: Welcome. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Answer (score 1):

you'll need two conditional formatting rules:

1. for `red`

   =and(today()>=H2+2,H2<>"",I2="")
2. for `yellow`

   =and(today()=H2+1,I2="")

[test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zzPBsz3xkcZOgaSowA48NTMHC_HYh05XCt88O8Vh5lI/edit?usp=sharing)